# Azure DevOps Deployment Group Target Offline

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops

I have a few deployment groups within Azure DevOps that I use for deployments. Within the groups are targets - 2 of them. In one group, both targets are online however in the other group, it shows only 1 is online and the same one online in this group shows offline. Here are the screenshots. You will notice that the same Target is showing healthy in one deployment group but unhealthy in another.

[image: Online]

[image: Offline]

Comment: Did this only occur for that particular deployment group, have you tried remove the target and re-add again, will this do the trick?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT I haven't tried re-adding it yet because it shows healthy elsewhere in other deployment groups for different pipelines. That is my next step in troubleshooting the issue; I was hoping there was a better answer. Thanks!

Comment: Besides, you can force the agents on the target machines to be upgraded to the latest version without needing to redeploy them by choosing the Upgrade targets command on the shortcut menu for a deployment group. You could also give a try with this.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT The issue turned out to be that someone just copied the agent from a different server - when i tried to run the agent manually, it gave me an error with an older server name saying the agent was already started. So I re-registered the agent and its back up now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the OP in the comments:

> The issue turned out to be that someone just copied the agent from a different server - when i tried to run the agent manually, it gave me an error with an older server name saying the agent was already started. So I re-registered the agent and its back up now